# TeX for Mavericks

Tags: installing, mac

I just (made the mistake of) upgrading to Mavericks for Mac. When I tried to compile one of my documents, I got the following error

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist.
```

I consider myself fairly good at LaTex but I'm not that great with the Mac. What does this error mean and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I did see that question; however, the Terminal command did not work. It placed a bin in my main user profile but did not help the compiling issue.

Comment: Can you check if pdflatex is actually there in `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`? If it is moved somewhere , you might have to find the location first before you do the terminal command. Are you using Texshop? Or you can check it by running `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/pdflatex`. If it is okay, you should see the version information. If not, you can fire up Texlive and reinstall pdflatex .

Comment: @Aung I am running TexShop, which has a bin folder

Comment: Is `pdflatex` in that location ? `ls /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin` . If so, can you run `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/pdflatex`? If not , you need to reinstall it?

Comment: No, I don't see it. But would reinstalling it work? With Mavericks being so new would reinstalling TexShop fix everything?

Comment: Look at http://tug.org/mactex/2013/faq/index.html#qt01 . And follow the instruction according to `QT.02: TeXShop refuses to start, or behaves strangely. Or, for example, you get the message:`

Comment: Thanks for all your help! TeXShop does the coding but I think MacTeX actually does the compiling. After reinstalling MacTex, I believe it puts the proper file paths in place and the problem was resolved and things compile as normal.